# Why Hibernate Session is taking so much time while inserting large records?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, plsql

I'm working in an application inorder to improve its performance.. In that, I have implemented **Hibernate Session** to store the values from an excel file. I'm storing the values using **pojo class object and Hibernate session**. Then I'm calling a ***PLSQL procedure*** to insert the values. When its executing the statement **session.save()**, its taking so much time for each row..

What's wrong with my strategy..?? Do I have any option rather than hibernate session..??

Comment: Just a comment - My approach will be, to transform the excel into sql, and execute sql/plsql into the db using their native client. The benefit is, you have a backup sql file that you can re-execute again anytime, FAST. Another benefit, you can play with the sql/plsql file later for some tweaking, in-case sql executions got problem half way.

Comment: Read up on Hibernate batch processing if you haven't: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

Comment: I don't really see what Hibernate does in this story. Apparently the stored procedure does all the work, plain JDBC with a CallableStatement is all you need.